# How to remove_filter that filters iframes in posts?

Tags: posts, tinymce, wysiwyg, filters

Which filter if removed allows iframes to be inserted into wordpress posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This filter does not. This feature is disabled in the visual editor TinyMCE.

```
function wpse49619_change_mce_options($initArray) {
    $ext = 'iframe[align|longdesc|name|width|height|frameborder|scrolling|marginheight|marginwidth|src]';
    if ( isset( $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',' . $ext;
    } else {
        $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $ext;
    }
    // maybe; set tiny paramter verify_html
    //$initArray['verify_html'] = false;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpse49619_change_mce_options');
```

Also you can use examples from [WPEngineer](http://wpengineer.com/1963/customize-wordpress-wysiwyg-editor/) how to enhancement TinyMCE.

Comment: Please put relevant code *in your answer* rather than merely linking to an external site. This one should be straight-forward enough that the code shouldn't be too onerous. :)

Comment: Ok @Chip Bennett, I added little code :)

Comment: Thanks! Now, I can put iframe directly into the editor BUT I used `media_send_to_editor($html)` to add `iframe` to editor but 'Add Media' screen hangs up. What could be the problem?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. This happens when Visual (WYSIWYG) is active. Works fine when HTML view is active.

Comment: Well this is because I was getting `<iframe ... />` from the Video API I am using. This causes _Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined_ in wp-tinymce.php. Should be `<iframe ...></iframe>`. HTML view auto converts this. WYSIWYG does not!