# How to display javascript banner in website header?

Tags: css, javascript, iframe

I recently purchased a theme which includes the option to display a banner in the header. The banner can be displayed using either a static image or javascript. The particular javascript code I'm using is for an Amazon banner ad and is displayed on the frontend via an iframe.

Using a static image the banner displays correctly as you can see here: http://capethemes.com/demo/portal/review/

When using the javascript code, however, the banner is not visible. Upon inspecting the source code, I discovered that the script tags and html containing block are there but the iframe element is missing.

Anyway, I was able to ascertain that it is a styling issue but am not sure how to resolve it. The following default theme styles are being applied to the `.headad` element:

```
.headad {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
margin: -65px 0 0 0;
}
```

...and here's the snippet used to display the banner:

```
echo '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="headad">';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($themnific_redux['tmnf-headad-script']);
echo '</div>';
```

### UPDATE #1

I've found I need to set a value for the width property on the `.headad` div to get the banner to display. Presumably this is because it's a responsive banner and therefore there has to be a width specified for the containing element so the appropriately sized banner image can be served.

Here's an overview of all the relevant details:

### HTML markup of banner ad and containing div (I have only included the outer HTML)

```
<div class="headad">
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script></script>
<div ><iframe></iframe></div>
</div>
```

### CSS for `.headad` element

```
.headad {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
margin: -65px 0 0 0;
}
```

This is the default theme CSS. I have changed `float: right;` to `float: none;` because `position: absolute;` is already being applied to the element. As I have already mentioned, to get the banner to display I have to set a value for the width property.

### iframe CSS

```
iframe {
border: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 728px;
height: 90px;
}
```

### UPDATE #2

I reproduced this on jsfiddle. You can view it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmee6nhp/1/).
Because this is a responsive banner, the width of the containing element has to be specified so the appropriately sized image can be returned. Maybe have to define a set of width property values using media queries for the `.headad` element?

Comment: The iframe is missing in the source and you believe it to be a styling issue? That sounds like ambitious CSS ;)

Comment: Yes, strange but true.

Comment: What I was trying to say is: you cannot style what isn't there. I believe that TinyMCE filters out iframes generally, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49619/how-to-remove-filter-that-filters-iframes-in-posts) for an example to fix that. Maybe that's all it needs in your case?

Comment: It's in the header, not the post. Actually, I'm using the exact same script in another ad block which appears at the bottom of single posts and that is working ok. If I apply the same CSS styles from that ad block (eg. display block, and 100% width) to the header ad, I can get the ad to display. That's how I know it's a styling issue.

Comment: @jrcollins Can you post a sample of the snippet that produces the iframe?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question to include the snippet.

Comment: @jrcollins Thank you. Since `$themnific_redux['tmnf-headad-script']` is a variable, any idea what this is equal to, or a snippet of what the HTML markup looks like when you view source?

Comment: The variable is equal to the amazon banner ad script.

Comment: Do you see where the element is on the page when you hover over the div? try adjusting the top margin value see if you get any changes.

Comment: @TurtleTread Thanks, I'll have another look at it.

Comment: Just looked at it and there is definitely a element with the class headad in the DOM ... but i cannot inspect it and styling has no effect.

Comment: Better make a jsfiddle or give an example of url that use the js banner to better assess the situation.

Comment: @jrcollins Well it seems to be blocked by ad blocker, it displays fine in Incognito. If you just change the class name to something else from ```headad```, something like ```head-banner```, it'd appear fine everywhere.

Give it a shot, once you confirm the fix, I'll post it as answer ;)

Comment: Please see my updated question for more details.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle. You can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmee6nhp/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As already stated in my question, to display the banner ad a width has to be specified for the containing `.headad` element so the correctly sized image can be displayed. This is because the `.headad` element has `position:absolute` applied to it and so has no inherent width.

The only way to display the banner ad across the full range of browser/screen sizes is to use multiple CSS media queries. Even then, it is necessary to make a number of other styling adjustments to account for changes in the relative heights of the various elements.

Anyway, I've decided it's just not worth pursuing this any further. I will edit the style sheet so that the banner ad is only displayed when the browser/screen size is large enough to accommodate the full sized banner.

Thank you to everyone who helped out with this question.

Comment: Why vote this down? Have you got any suggestions on how to answer it?

Answer (score 1):

It's there and visible in Incognito mode, it's being blocked by one of the adBlocker extension that you might be using in your browser.

The best workaround would be is to change the class from `headad` to something more generic like `head-banner`.

Make sure you update the style in your theme/plugin.

[image: Blocked by adblock]

Banner with updated class:

[image: Banner with updated class and style]

Comment: well obvious :D i feel a bit dumb now ;)

Comment: No, as I explained in my question, the ad shown in the theme demo is a static image and not a script. It's an Amazon banner ad script that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @jrcollins Is there a URL to check this live?

Answer (score 0):

Just digged into this problem with dev tools. Somehow it gets computed with display none ... i don't know exactly why this happens. Seems like there is some strange inline style that gets added async …

Try this:

```
#header.left-header .headad {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: A static image is shown on the theme demo. The problem I'm having is with a script which is displayed via an iframe on the front end.

Comment: Well then it would be best for us if you give us some example on wich we can view your problem.